# AD и LDAP принципы работы

Tags: администрирование, active-directory, ldap

Я только собираюсь осваивать эти вещи,  хотелось бы очень коротко получить разъяснение.
По факту эти службы управляют  :

- добавлением и авторизацией пользователей
- управлением настройками ОС
- удаленным управлением ПК
- удаленным администрированием - централизованная установка ПО.
- авторизует на другие сервера (БД, хранилища, сервисы)

Чего не делает  :

- не хранит файлы , но авторизует на сервера хранилища ?

Дополните списки пожалуйста. Мне нужно общее представление.
Литература сильно толстая чтоб выделить основной функционал ,  да и тошнотная - особенно от майкрософта.. чтобы понять что 2+2 =  4 надо прочитать от 3 до 15 страниц воды.

Спасибо.

Comment: С установкой софта - частично. Только если это msi. Если нет - костыли на cmd\powershell. Хранение - контроллер домена - такая же винда на таком же компе - никто не мешает в неё закинуть файло.

Comment: домен данные хранит централизовано?  те накачал я там гигов 10 всякой мукулатуры и она лежит где ?  в домене ?  в локальном пк ?

Comment: Куда закинешь - там и будет лежать. Закинешь на локальный комп на диск Д - будешь лежать на диске Д. Закинешь в `\\you-domain-controller\sysvol\UUID\folder` - будет лежать на контроллере.

Comment: Да. Если включишь `перемещаемые профили` - будет храниться и на рабочем столе и на контроллере.